# Error in Switch statement

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

So this a the line of the code where the error appears :

```
switch (ResultCalculation) {// expected indentifier or '/'

    case = 0
        Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
        break;

    case = 1
        Result = FirstNumber - SecondNumber;
        break;

    case = 2
        Result = FirstNumber * SecondNumber;
        break;

    case = 3
        Result = FirstNumber / SecondNumber;

    default :// default statement not in switch statement 
        break ;// break statement not in loop or switch statement
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - it should be:

```
switch (ResultCalculation) {

  case 0: // <<< *** note the syntax for the case labels! ***
    Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    break;

  case 1:
    Result = FirstNumber - SecondNumber;
    break;

  // ...

  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks ! it Should work now , men stack overflow is superfast i posted this question like 10 min ago and you already answered

Comment: Ok So is corrected my error but this other one appeared :............................................................ DisplayLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",Result];// expected identifier or '/'

Comment: OK - read the error message, understand what it means, look at the line in question, fix the error. If after trying this you still can't fix it then post another question. You might also want to get a good book on iOS/Objective-C programming and study that.

Comment: Thanks Paul R yes indeed I think I should get a good book . But I don't know wich do you have any idea

Comment: You can get the Objective C 2.0 reference for free as a PDF, and there are lots of good iOS books on Amazon.